# How to make REST calls from Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: gwt, rest, cxf

I have my restful CXF service producing JSON with default JSON provider. I want to know if we can use GWT to build client which will user the restful service. Will it work ? If not, what would be a simple work around for this type ?

Thank you.
regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work.  See [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html).  Here's a quote:

> GWT does not limit you to this one RPC mechanism or server side development environment. You are free to integrate with other RPC mechanisms, such as JSON using the GWT supplied RequestBuilder class, JSNI methods or a third party library.

Comment: np!  GWT with a JSON-based backend interfact is a pretty popular (and pretty smart, IMHO) architecture.

Comment: JSNI and JavaScript Overlay Types are very useful when working with a JSON service.